# How to find crossties between rails with openCV?

Tags: opencv, python

I have this image and I would like to find where the crossties are (either bounding boxes or masks works). Crossties are the horizontal blocks between the two rails. Just the rails in the middle are sufficient.

I have been struggling for quite a while now. I found the function `cv2.HoughLinesP` but I could not make it work.

Has anyone ever done something similar or know how to do it?

It would be very helpful.

[image]

```py
# 213, 205, 210
# 207, 200, 204
# 201, 195, 199
# 215, 208, 206
# 200, 195, 192

import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('out2168.png'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img = img[:, 300:400]
canny = cv2.Canny(img, 30, 120)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(canny, 1, np.pi / 360, 20)
for rho, theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a * rho
    y0 = b * rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * a)
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * a)
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow('rail', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

References:

- [OpenCV houghLinesP parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609719/opencv-houghlinesp-parameters)
- https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

Comment: Please, post whatever solution you’ve got so far. Why is `cv2.HoughLinesP` giving you problems? With that said, there’s a lot going on in that picture, the cross-ties at the horizon aren’t even humanly recognizable, so be prepared to adjust your expectations accordingly.

Comment: Yes if I could just get the cross-ties in the foreground it would be amazing already. I pasted my progress above (after truncating to have a simpler image to work with).

Comment: I am quite a beginner at this. I have to apologize for that.

Comment: Try running HoughLines on adaptiveThreshold'ed image instead of canny and see if it finds rails.