# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable Crash

Tags: python, opencv, nonetype

The code is:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(masked_image, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), minLineLength=min_line_len, maxLineGap=max_line_gap)

    # Create an empty black image
    line_image = np.zeros((masked_image.shape[0], masked_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    for line in lines: #where the error is happing
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), [0, 0, 255], 20)
```

With this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linefindinginvideo.py", line 48, in <module>
    for line in lines:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

For the full code go to my GitHub https://github.com/jimhoggey/SelfdrivingcarForza/blob/main/lanemarkinginvideo.py

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609719/opencv-houghlinesp-parameters

Answer (score 1):

It means that this line:

```
cv2.HoughLinesP(masked_image, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), minLineLength=min_line_len, maxLineGap=max_line_gap)
```

returned `None`, and the reasoning for it is that it was unable to detect any lines. You will need to adjust some values to get the detection to work properly, or it could be a case where there really are no lines in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
a simple statement that checks the variable is it is none before the for statement.

so we add the line

`if lines is not None:`

which means our final statement looks like this

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(masked_image, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), minLineLength=min_line_len, maxLineGap=max_line_gap)
line_image = np.zeros((masked_image.shape[0], masked_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

 if lines is not None: # the fix
      for line in lines:
          for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
              cv2.line(line_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), [0, 0, 255], 20)
```